# select date in ikal calender show two data in tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have implement ikal or native calender in my app.its working fine.I have adding some events in it.add

ing of event is also working fine but when we click on event in calender then its data show into table

view.its fine but when we close our app and again select that event it show now twice the data which

we want in table view.when we again close and again select event it show tha data thrice and so on.

Please any body know that reason that why the data are not show only in single time in table view.

Comment: here your this problem solved or not??

Comment: oh ok ok then fine dude..

Comment: provide us with an answer

Comment: In EventViewController class under this method: - (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate  I have added following lines from removing event: [events removeAllObjects];...

Comment: please give your source code link. that type of calendar add in my app so please give a link .thanks